# The bio structure in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, block-device

I am reading Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love. I don't understand this paragraph about the `bio` structure:

> The basic container for block I/O within the kernel is the bio structure, which is defined in `<linux/bio.h>`. This structure represents block I/O operations that are in flight (active) as a list of segments. A segment is a chunk of a buffer that is contiguous in memory. Thus, individual buffers need not be contiguous in memory. By
>   allowing the buffers to be described in chunks, the bio structure provides the capability for the kernel to perform block I/O operations of even a single buffer from multiple locations in memory. Vector I/O such as this is called scatter-gather I/O.

1. What exactly does `flight(active)` means?
2. "As a list of segments" -- are we talking about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation) segmentation?
3. What does "By allowing the buffers ... in memory" mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Block Devices are such device which deals with a chunk (512, 1024 bytes) of data during an I/O transaction. "struct bio" is available for block I/O operations from Kernel-Space. This structure is commonly used in block device driver development.

*Q1) What exactly does flight(active) means?*

Block devices are usually implemented with a File-System meant for storing files. Now when ever an user-space application initiates a File I/O operation (read, write), the kernel in turn initiates a sequence of Block I/O operation through File-System Manager. The "struct bio" keeps track of all Block I/O transactions (initiated by user app) that is to be processed. That's what is mentioned here as **flight/active** regions.

*"Q2) As a list of segments" -- are we talking about this segmentation?*

Memory buffers are required by the kernel to hold data to/from Block device.

In kernel there are two possiblilites in which the memory is allocated.

1. Virtual Address Continuous - Physical Address Continuous (Using kmalloc() - Provides good Performance but limited in size)
2. Virtual Address Continuous - Physical Address Non-continuous (Using vmalloc() - For huge memory size requirement)

Here a segment indicates the first type i.e. continuous physical memory which is used for block IO transfer. List of segment indicates a set of such continuous physical memory regions. Note that the list elements are non-continuous memory segments.

*Q3) What does "By allowing the buffers ... in memory" mean?*

Scatter-gather is feature which allows data transfer from/to multiple non-continuous memory location to/from device, in a single shot (read/write transaction). Here "struct bio" keeps record of multiple segments that is to be processed. Each segment is a continuous memory region whereas multiple segments are non-continuous with one another. "struct bio" provides capability to the kernel to perform scatter-gather feature.

Comment: What it means by "perform block I/O operations of even a single buffer from multiple locations in memory", I think a single buffer should be contiguous in memory or is it that its contiguous in virtual memory but non-contiguous in physical i.e case-2 of memory allocation?

Answer (score 3):

1. "In flight" means an operation that has been requested, but hasn't been initiated yet.
2. "Segment" here means a range of memory to be read or written, a contiguous
   piece of the data to be transferred as part of the operation.
3. "Scatter/gather I/O" is meant by *scatter* operations that take a contiguous range of data on disk and distributes pieces of it into memory, *gather* takes separate ranges of data in memory and writes them contiguously to disk. (Replace "disk" by some suitable device in the preceding.) Some I/O machinery is able to do this in one operation (and this is getting more common).

Answer (score 1):

1) "In flight" means "in progress"
2) No
3) Not quite sure :)